# Ruby: how to insert a conditional into a string concatenation

Tags: ruby

In a string concatenation, is it possible to include a conditional directly into the statement?

In the example below, I want `"my dear"` to be concatenated only if the `dear` list is not empty.

```
dear = ""

string = "hello" + " my dear" unless dear.empty? + ", good morning!"
```

But the result is an error: undefined method '+' for true

I know the alternative would be to define an additional variable before this statement but I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 14):

It is easier and more readable with interpolation instead of concatenation:

```
dear = ""

string = "hello#{ ' my dear' unless dear.empty? }, good morning!"
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I agree

Answer (score 6):

In this case, you would be better off using ternary operators.

```
string = "hello" + (dear.empty? ? "" : " my dear") + ", good morning!"
```

The syntax goes like

```
condition ? if true : if false
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something *cutie*

```
dear = ""
"hello%s, good morning!" % (' my dear' unless dear.empty?)
# => "hello, good morning!"
dear = "val"
"hello%s, good morning!" % (' my dear' unless dear.empty?)
# => "hello my dear, good morning!"
```

Comment: it should be `hello%s...` without space. And I believe `"hello%s, good morning!" % (' my dear' unless dear.empty?)` is more cute ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### I will share my solution.

```
2.7.0 :040 > dear = ""
2.7.0 :041 > string = "hello #{dear.empty? ? "World" : dear}, good morning!"
2.7.0 :042 > string
 => "hello World, good morning!"
2.7.0 :043 > dear = "Test"
2.7.0 :044 > string = "hello #{dear.empty? ? "World" : dear}, good morning!"
2.7.0 :045 > string
 => "hello Test, good morning!"
2.7.0 :046 >
```